# Pagination after filtering on CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, pagination

I have a question. I have a pagination mechanism that is very simple that is combined with WPF buttons and data grid, and it looks like:

```
    public CatalogViewModel()
    {
        this._catalog = new CatalogContexct();

        DbQuery<Candidate> candidatesValues = this._catalog.Candidates.Include("commendation");
        this._totalItems = candidatesValues.Count();

        this._candidates = candidatesValues.ToArray()
            .OrderBy(c => c.Firstname).Skip(this.Start).Take(this._itemCount).ToList();

        this._filters = new Dictionary<string, Predicate<Candidate>>();            

        var candidates = new ListCollectionView(this._candidates);
        this.CandidateView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(candidates);

        this.FirstameCommand = new RelayCommand(FilterFirstname, param => this._canExecute);
        this.LastnameCommand = new RelayCommand(FilterLastname, param => 

        CandidateView.Filter = FilterCandidates;

        //should be something else to limit view to page so filter can be done on whole source not only part of it like above
    }
```

But as i describe, I need to filter value before paginatio or paginate filtered values of this.CandidateView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(candidates);

Is is possible?

I would be passible if i filter on collection manually and pass that values to view, but I wonder if there is a easier way to do it then manipulating data manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the source collection using the same Predicate that you use to filter the `ICollectionView` with:

```
this._candidates = candidatesValues.Where(FilterCandidates).OrderBy(c => c.Firstname).Skip(this.Start).Take(this._itemCount).ToList();
```

Then you don't need to filter or even use an ICollectionView at all. You could bind directly to the filtered and paged source collection.